# Problem with update to chromedriver / Chrome 122.0.6261.95

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We always use the latest Chrome for our automation. The appropriate Chrome driver is provided via the Selenium Manager.
This has worked very well so far. However, when updating to Chrome v. 122.0.6261.95, I had a problem with one of my functions:

The function is supposed to insert a screenshot into a field.
To do this, a new tab is first opened, which calls up an image via a URL.
This image is copied with CTRL+C and the tab is closed again.
Now a field is clicked in the application and the image is inserted there with CTRL+V.

The code is below.

Unfortunately, this is no longer possible in headless mode. In "normal Chrome" mode, where I can watch the execution, it works perfectly. Both modes work with Chrome version v. 121.

Does anyone have an idea? Is there any better code for inserting an image into a field?

The following settings in headless mode:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
options.addArguments("--disable-site-isolation-trials");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Here is the function

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", "IMAGE_URL");
            Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
            for (String WindowHandle : handles) {
                if (!WindowHandle.equals(CurrentWindow)) {                                  
                    driver.switchTo().window(WindowHandle);
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();    
                }
            }
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//IMG[1]"))).click().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(1000);
//close window
close_Tab();
Thread.sleep(1000);
            
driver.findElement(By.xpath(XpathToClick)).click();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH))).click().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("v").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```